# How can search posts with specific frontmatter in collections(liquid)

Tags: collections, jekyll

I have some problem in assigning Front Matter in post. So here is Front Matters of a post in colloction named with _programming:
/_programming/somepost.md

```
---
title: "Layout: Header Image (Horizontal)"
header:
  image: /assets/images/unsplash-image-1.jpg
  caption: "Photo credit: [**Unsplash**](https://unsplash.com)"
categories:
  - Layout
  - Uncategorized
tags:
  - edge case
  - featured image
  - image
  - layout
---

This post should display a **header image**, if the theme supports it.

Non-square images can provide some unique styling issues.

This post tests a horizontal header image.
```

> this post is from minimal-mistakes

However, I have many post which has `categories: Layout`. Posts can have only one categories or a few of categoires, like above.

I want to get post in collection. For this I tried this code:

```rb
---
permalink: /study/layout/
title: Layout
subject: Layout
layout: study_theme
---

{% assign subject=page.subject %}
{% for temp in study.programming %}
  {% if temp.categories == subject %}
    <a href="{{ temp.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}"> 
     <p>{{ temp.title }}</p>
    </a>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

And this code:

```rb
---
permalink: /study/layout/
title: Layout
subject: Layout
layout: study_theme
---

{% assign subject=page.subject %}
{% for temp in study.programming %}
  {% if temp.categories contains subject %}  //only here changed
    <a href="{{ temp.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}"> 
     <p>{{ temp.title }}</p>
    </a>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But those codes are not working. please help me. I can't see any posts in page.

Comment: What is the `study.programming` in `{% for temp in study.programming %}` ?. Is it `site.programming` you're looking for ?

Comment: Yes, study.programming is floder that madr for storing posts. And I'm looking for posts which have specific front matter, like `categories: Layout`

Comment: How do you assign a value to `study.programming` ?

Comment: sorry that I saw it too late, I use site.programming to assign it. Not a study.programming. I typed this for man who only knows about liquid